# NodeJS express issue with module

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new with node.js and I probably installed it wrong, once I installed It worked great, but now, after a while I can't start node server anymore.

when I'm trying "node debug server.js"
I got this
Error: No such native module express

Here is my code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');

});

app.get('/wheel', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/wheel.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('subscription', function(msg){
    console.log('subscription: ' + msg);
    io.emit('subscription', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Debug:

```
break in server.js:1
  1 var app = require('express')();
  2 var http = require('http').Server(app);
  3 var io = require('socket.io')(http);
debug> var app = require('express')();
Error: No such native module express
```

I installed express with --save and -g parameters, so here is version

```
~/sandbox/dpr# express -V
4.13.1
```

Can anybody lead me what is wrong with my server.
Thank you.

**UPDATED**

Here is full debug output

```
debug> var app = require('express')();
Error: No such native module express
    at NativeModule.require (node.js:854:13)
    at repl:1:11
    at Interface.controlEval (_debugger.js:969:21)
    at repl.js:249:20
    at Interface.controlEval (_debugger.js:981:5)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
debug>
```

Comment: do you see express in you `node_modules` folder?

Comment: yes, there is next folders: "express", "express-generator", "socket.io"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `server.js` file is located in the main directory alongside your `node_modules` as such:'

```
app_directory
├──server.js
├──_node_modules
   ├──express
```

Comment: This is exactly how it's located.